# git master/staging/production setup, how to revert staging?

Tags: git, deployment

I just read 
http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/version-control/branching-best-practices.html

They talk about `master` -> `staging` -> `production` setup, and I think it makes sense.

One thing bothers me, what should I do if I find a critical bug at staging?

i.e. suppose there are commits that needs to go to production and there are commits that need to be dropped at staging branch.

I guess I need ways to do the followings.

```
1. un-merge commits from `staging` which I don't need
2. um-merge the same commits from `master` so that `staging` can merge other commits
```

Are there recommended way of doing the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually people prefer not to rewrite history, since your project can lose vital detail and information about design decisions. What I would suggest, then, is that any changes you decide you don't want in production, you [`revert` them](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert). That way, you remove the unwanted changes, but preserve the chain of events that tells you why you made the decision to drop certain changes or features.

To use this command, run `git revert <commit>`.

Once you've removed your unwanted commit from `staging`, merge `staging` into your `master` branch:

- `git checkout master`
- `git merge staging`

Comment: I think i'll do `git revert` from master and merge that to staging. (kinda backward from your description). Following the flow of master->staging->production. Does it sound better?

Answer (score 0):

I'm the co-author of the guide. First of all let me correct you about staging -> production part. The guide doesn't suggest merging staging into production. Staging is a sandbox branch that that's not meant to be merged into anything else because it can contain branches that are unfinished or were cancelled.

If you found a bug in staging that was already merged into stable (and production), simply revert it in stable with "git revert", merge stable into production and deploy. You can then revert it in staging as well or re-create staging from scratch from your stable branch.

When there's a lot of features/fixes being merged into staging every day and some of them are later cancelled, it's a good idea to "flush" the staging branch from time to time from the master branch, then merge only relevant things into it.